# Pivoting SQL tables | Convert column value to column headers

Tags: sql

i wrote a script that queries the table and returns the information as such:

| Customer_Name | Customer_id | Type | Quota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_1 | 1 | type_1 | 50 |
| customer_1 | 1 | type_2 | 40 |
| customer_1 | 1 | type_3 | 30 |
| Customer_2 | 2 | type_1 | 30 |
| Customer_2 | 2 | type_2 | 40 |
| Customer_2 | 2 | type_4 | 60 |

I want to be able to present the data as such:

| Customer_name | Customer_id | type_1 | type_2 | type_3 | type_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_1 | 1 | 50 | 40 | 30 | 0 |
| customer_2 | 1 | 30 | 40 | 0 | 60 |

basically convert the value of third column as column headers and use the fourth column value as the value for those headers.

i am using SQL 2016 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Do you mean **SQL Server 2016**? There is no such thing as SQL 2016. You should provide the DBMS information by adding a tag for it along with the SQL tag. There are also many existing questions here about pivoting data in SQL Server - have you made any effort to research that topic here and to write the SQL yourself to attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Ken, i did do the research and went through multiple post within stack overflow about pivot tables. I also tried doing it on my own, whilst using www3 resources and learning as i write code. Just can't seem to comprehend the data structure for given problem.

Comment: *I did do the research* isn't anywhere in your question. Neither is *I also tried doing it on my own*, because if you did there should be some SQL in your post that shows that effort. Keep in mind that the only information we have available is what you put in your question - if it's not in your post, it doesn't exist. You should [edit] your question to address those issues, as well as the one I raised in the first two sentences of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregataion:

```
select Customer_Name, Customer_id,
       sum(case when type = 'type_1' then quota else 0 end) as type_1,
       sum(case when type = 'type_2' then quota else 0 end) as type_2,
       sum(case when type = 'type_3' then quota else 0 end) as type_3,
       sum(case when type = 'type_4' then quota else 0 end) as type_4
from t
group by Customer_Name, Customer_id;
```

Note that the `else 0` guarantees that you'll get a zero for the missing values rather than `NULL`.